# cd command won't change directory. Comand prompt

Tags: windows-8, cmd

I have windows 8, and I'm using the command prompt. It says C:\Windows\System32>
and if i try to change directory, it says "The system cannot find the path specified."

In this case, im typing the exact following command: `cd desktop`

It works fine on my windows 7 computer. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Because Desktop is not in the System32 folder; it is in the Users folder.  I don't know why it does it in Windows 7.

Comment: Even with Windows 7, it should not be in System32 folder as well. A misconfiguration.

Answer (score 4):

Because your desktop folder is not in `c:\windows\system32`. Presumably, your Windows 7 cmd prompt started you in your user folder instead of system32.

Try this instead.

```
cd %userprofile%\Desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in windows 10. When I opened CMD as a user, the default path was on my user profile in which my desktop is set. So, when I wrote `cd desktop`, it found my desktop right away (below image).
[image]

However, when I run CMD as an **administrator**, the default path changes to `C:\Windows\system32` which is my **SystemRoot**. Within this path, there is no desktop folder. Therefor, when you type `cd desktop it will produce an error (below image).

[image: Image two: CMD run as administrator]

What you need to do is to address the whole file path in your `cd` command. In this way your computer will know where your file is located exactly (below image)

[image: Image three: cd in CMD admin with complete path]