# Why does ls ~/.ssh work but not cd ~/.ssh?

Tags: bash, cmd, ls, cd

If the `ls` command lists the contents of a directory, then some output to `ls <directory` would seem to indicate that a directory exists.

For example, this is what I get:

```
> ls ~/.ssh
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

But why then, when I type `cd ~/.ssh` do I get

```
> cd ~/.ssh
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

?

Why can I list the contents of this directory but not navigate to it?

**I am using Windows 8**

Comment: You're using `ls` on Windows 8?

Comment: Maybe this can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748579/cd-command-wont-change-directory-comand-prompt

Comment: CodyBugstein..Wat OS are you using its win or linux??

Comment: `bash` and `ls` are not typically provided by Microsoft. Have you added software such as Cygwin or MSYS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This answer is under the assumption that you are using the command prompt to execute these commands.*

The reason that you can `ls` the directory but not `cd` to it, is because the `ls` command comes from a library that you downloaded that makes `ls` work on windows.

In contrast, your `cd` command is being executed from Windows, not from the library you downloaded.

In short, `ls` knows how to parse the tilde (`~`) as home, but windows doesn't know how to parse `~`.  try it:  `cd ~`. it won't work.

Comment: Ah ok I don't remember downloading anything for `ls`. How can I do the same for `cd`?

Comment: Can you help me figure out what `ls` program I have?

Comment: well, i'd recommend consolidating your environment.  since you are trying to use unix commands, use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).  don't mix and match different executables between linux and windows. i.e., don't use command prompt if you intend to use unix commands :)

Comment: `where ls` in almost all command prompts reveals where your executable lies

Comment: So how do I actually navigate to `.ssh`? I am not sure where the actual directory lives

Comment: `cd %USERPROFILE%\.ssh` should do the trick, assuming that you're using cmd and the .ssh folder lives under your userprofile